# Proving that $f$ is a bijection.

Tags: functions, proof-writing

Here is the question:

> Suppose $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ and $g:Y\longrightarrow X$ satisfy $$\forall x\in X.(g\circ f)(x)=x,\,\forall y\in Y.(f\circ g)(y)=y$$ Prove that $f$ is a bijection, with $f^{-1}=g$.

To show that $g$ is the inverse of $f$, I basically need to show
$$\forall y\in Y.\big(g(y)=x\Leftrightarrow f(x)=y\big)$$

But I'm so confused on where to go from here, any ideas?

Comment: To prove that $f$ is a bijection, you need to show that $f$ is both injective and surjective, i.e.$$\forall x_1,x_2\in X( f(x_1)=f(x_2)\Rightarrow x_1=x_2)$$ and $$\forall y\in Y \:\exists x\in X(f(x)=y)$$

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by other comments and answers, you need to show $f$ is injective and surjective, although this isn't the part of the question you specifically asked about.

To prove that $f^{-1}=g$, prove each required implication separately. For example, you could start by letting $g(y)=x$ and try to show that $f(x)=y$. To do this, look at the second property that $f$ and $g$ have - if $(f\circ g)(y)=y$, and $g(y)=x$, then... The other implication is similar.

Comment: Isn't $f\circ g=1_Y$ and $g\circ f=1_X$ the *definition* for being $g=f^{-1}$?

Comment: It doesn't appear to be the definition the OP is using, given the phrasing of both the problem they are trying to solve and the clause beginning "I basically need to show...".

Comment: Well, then I'm asking *what* the definition can be. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg I'm not sure I'm following - the OP has a definition ($g(y)=x\iff f(x)=y$) in the question.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Injectivity.**

If $x\neq y$ and $f(x)=f(y)$ then $g(f(x))=g(f(y))$, i.e. $x=y$, which is a contradiction. So $f$ is injective.

2. **Surjectivity**

For all $y\in Y$ there exists a (unique by injectivity) $x\in X$ s.t. $f(x)=y$. Just take $x:=g(y)$; in fact $f(x)=f(g(y))=y$, as claimed.